# Inequalities on the surface of a sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, inequality

Suppose $S$ is the surface of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ above the $xy$ plane. Can we determine the following inequalities on $S$ without sketching the surface (as that's quite hard to sketch/visualise):

$-a \le x \le a$ and $-\sqrt{a^2-x^2} \le y \le \sqrt{a^2-x^2}.$

Comment: It is simply all the the semi-sphere over the $x-y$ plane.

Comment: It's very easy to sketch. Just copy the figure at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Moment_of_inertia_hollow_sphere.svg, but leave off the bottom half of the circle.

Comment: As a previous comment hinted, the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ implies both of your inequalities. Do you need help proving that? (By the way, you don't need to sketch the surface to prove this; it wouldn't actually help you. To visualize some other problems, however, it might be good to learn to draw a simple hemisphere.)

Comment: @DavidK Yes. I know where the upper bounds come from I think but I can't get the lower bounds.

Comment: @DavidK I've tried this: let $z=0$ then $x^2+y^2 \le a^2 \implies y^2 \le a^2 - x^2  \implies |y| \le \sqrt{a^2-x^2} $. Similarly $|x| \le \sqrt{a^2-y^2}$ thus $\min(-\sqrt{a^2-y^2}) \le x \le \max(\sqrt{a^2-y^2}) \iff -|a| \le x \le |a|$.

Comment: Good catch putting the absolute value in the last set of inequalities; the original inequalities for $x$ work only if $a$ is non-negative. I missed that point earlier. You seem to be doing very well here; the only thing I think really needs to change is that you don't need to set $z=0$ to get $x^2+y^2\leq a^2$; you only need $z=0$ if you want to write $=$ instead of $\leq$.

Comment: It looks like you know that $\lvert p \rvert \leq \lvert q \rvert$ is equivalent to $-\lvert q \rvert \leq p \leq \lvert q \rvert$, because you used something like that for $x$. so you should have everything you need except possibly the ability to remove the absolute value signs around $a$ (which you can do if it was already given that $a\geq 0$; if there is _not_ a reason to say that $a\geq0$, I think the answer you have given for $x$ is better than the one you were to show).

Comment: @DavidK Many thanks! Indeed there was no condition on $a$.